# Deferred validation with Backbone

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js, deferred

I'm using the [backbone validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) library for validating my backbone model. I want to create a custom validation that will go to the server and check to see if an id is unique. My problem is that I'm having trouble handling the deferred response correctly.

```
validation: {
    'userId': {
        required    : true,
        fn  : function(val, attr, computedState){
            this.validateUniqueUserId(val, attr, computedState).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                console.log('got response');
                if (data.metadata.totalCount) {
                    return 'User Id must be unique'
                }
            });
        }
    }
},

validateUniqueUserId: function(val, attr, computedState){
    return this.validateOnServer({
        url     : 'myurl/?userId=' + val,
        attr    : 'userId',
        val     : val
    });
},

validateOnServer: function(options){
    this.trigger('validating', { attr: options.attr });

    return Backbone.ajax({
        url                 : options.url,
        type                : 'GET',
        ignoreErrorGlobally : false
    });
}
```

So my call goes to the server and correctly validates the required attribute and returns the response I expect. The problem, I believe, is the context of the line `return 'User Id must be unique'`. I hit this line, as expected, when a `userId` already exists but it looks like this line needs to be outside the `done` callback.

For example, the following works as expected:

```
validation: {
    'userId': {
        required    : true,
        fn  : function(val, attr, computedState){
            return 'User Id must be unique'
        }
    }
},
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Although I have no evidence that it's valid to return a promise from the validation fn, the simplest thing to try is `return this.validateUniqueUserId(val, attr, computedState).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){`. If that doesn't work, you will have to do something other than return the 'User Id must be unique' string from the inner function. I don't know what that something might be.